# IIS App Pool Crashes with AppPoolIdentity identity, not with NetworkService

Tags: iis, application-pools

> OS: Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> IIS: 7.5
>
> No Managed Code

I am trying to nail down the issue here.  I am not sure if it was precipitated by some change from a group policy (I don't have any control over that) or from installing some Windows Update.

All of a sudden after a reboot, none of my sites would work, they all respond with `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.`  The app pools were stopped and there are 5 warnings (EventID 5009, EventSourceName WAS) and 1 error (EventID 5002, EventSourceName WAS) in the System event logs and 5 errors (EventID 2276, EventSourceName W3SVC-WP) in the Appliation event logs (per app pool).

I switched all my sites to a single app pool and change the identity to NetworkService and they all work.  This however seems like a security/scale issue?

I downloaded DebugDiag 2 and tried to get a dump, however it never seemed to trigger.  I also try to find the process in Process Explorer, but any app pool not using the NetworkService identity doesn't show up.

I don't know how else to look for the root cause.

---

EDIT @Lex Li

Checked my Debug Tool log and found this

> [7/19/2018 3:29:02 PM] New process found:        Process Name -
> w3wp.exe             Process ID - 4652   Process Identity - IIS
> APPPOOL\Test Pool                    Web application pool name - Test
> Pool
> [7/19/2018 3:29:02 PM] Attach Debugger:          Process Name -
> w3wp.exe             Process ID - 4652   Control Script - C:\Program
> Files\DebugDiag\Scripts\CrashRule_WebAppPool_Test Pool.vbs
> Script Error
> Error Code - 0x80070002
> Error Source [DbgSvc.Controller.1]
> Error Description []
> Line 93, Column 2
> [7/19/2018 3:29:03 PM] Process Exited:           Process Name -
> w3wp.exe             Process ID - 4652   Web application pool name -
> Test Pool

However that only shows up once, and can't reproduce it.

Comment: Even if no dumps are created, Debug Diag does write to its log files what happened. You might take a look there first.

Comment: Very likely you need to try other approaches (procdump, or other tools). Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com if you can. You hit a non-trivial case, which might indicate your server has been modified in an unexpected way.